# What diagram tool is used to generate microservice architecture

Tags: diagram

what diagram tool is used to generate the following diagram? Thanks.

[image]

[source link](https://dzone.com/articles/building-microservices-inter-process-communication-2)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it's asking for help to find a tool. It would seem to make far more sense to use the comment section there to ask what they used.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that creates this diagram automatically from code/documentation?

Comment: I am looking for this diagram, too. I'll be glad if anyone could share this tool.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/introduction-to-microservices/#comment-2265681647) on nginx.com, it's with OmniGraffle. Since the author of your source link works too in NGinx, it is coherent.